# JavaScript add arrays to existing array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I've below code snippet

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "name": "Attestation Component 1",
        "values": [
            {
                "component": "Attestation Component 1"
            },
            {
                "component": "Attestation Component 1"
            },
            {
                "component": "Attestation Component 1",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Attestation Component 2",
        "values": [
            {
                "id": "10005884",
                "url": "https://www.msn.com",
                "bfaId": "G44.5.3.1N/A",
                "component": "Attestation Component 2"
            },
            {
                "id": "10005883",
                "url": "https://www.hotmail.com",
                "bfaId": "G44.5.3.2N/A",
                "component": "Attestation Component 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Attestation Component 3",
        "values": [
            {
                "id": "10005882",
                "url": "https://www.rediffmail.com",
                "bfaId": "G44.5.3.3N/A",
                "component": "Attestation Component 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]

const bool = arr.map(group => group.values.every(val => val.id));
console.log(bool);
```

I've three object with name Attestation Component 1, Attestation Component 2 ,Attestation Component 3. I'm getting the expected output as false, true, true. What's the reason for this? I want to add the property to the existing array of object as something `isInvalid: true/false` below `name`

Expected O/P (add property in each object with below key value pairs)
`isInvalid: true/false`

Comment: Your algorithm is a little weird, what are you trying to do ? Why do you filter the booleans values to keep only the one that are `false`?

Comment: Are you looking for `const bool = arr.some(group => group.values.some(val => val.id))` instead, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpAjXW)?  I'm not sure what your expected output is, especially the part where you're filtering a bunch of booleans and only returning the `false` ones, and then making them into *strings*.  What's the goal here, exactly?  Can you spell it out?

Comment: Try to avoid chaining methods too much like this, it makes debugging much harder. Also, could you please clarify what your output should be? Should it be ```[false, true, true]``` ?

Comment: Try: `const bool = !arr.some(obj => obj.values.some(val => 'id' in val));`

Comment: If your expected output is `"false"` then you've gotten your expected output already and you haven't demonstrated a problem. Presumably you have some actual input/output pair that your implementation fails to satisfy; maybe show us one of those instead?

Comment: Maybe instead of everyone just _guessing_ what the OP wants perhaps flag the question on details/wait until they clarify their question.

Comment: @jcalz I've change the strategy updated the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is because your algorithm is incorrect. The `every` method will check if all the objects have an id, but that is not what you want right ?

So try this instead

```
const bool = arr.map(group => group.values.some(val => val.id));
```

Comment: if all you do is change `every` for `some` then his code will return an empty string

Comment: Well apparently he only want to transform to a string an array of `false`, that's on him. Changing `every` for `some` will have the expected behavior

Answer (score -3):

Instead of every(), you should use some().

```
const bool = arr.map(group => group.values.some(val => val.id)).filter(bool => !bool).toString();
```

every() method is used to check whether all the elements of the array satisfy the given condition or not. The Array. some() method is used to check whether at least one of the elements of the array satisfies the given condition or not.

Comment: if all you do is change `every` for `some` then his code will return an empty string

Comment: Of course, he is using toString(). I don't know why he needs to do that, but this will accomplish what he is asking.